# Get list of roles for all clients in keycloak

Tags: keycloak, roles

I'm working on an application that authentication and authorization are handling with Keyclock.

So we have a scenario that we should list all of the roles from our client, `realm-management` and realm roles, for assiging to a specific user.

We need `realm-management` roles for assign `view-user`, `query-user` to a spesific user,to able query or view user list from the Keycloak.

I know we can get a client roles by following API:

`GET KEYCLOACK_BASE_URL + "/admin/realms/" + REALM + "/clients/{clientId}/roles"`

But if we want to get all roles we should call above API for three times.

First: `GET KEYCLOACK_BASE_URL + "/admin/realms/" + REALM + "/clients/ABC_id/roles"`

Second: `GET KEYCLOACK_BASE_URL + "/admin/realms/" + REALM + "/clients/realm-management_id/roles"`

Third: `GET KEYCLOACK_BASE_URL + "/admin/realms/" + REALM + "/roles"`

Is there a better solution for get all the roles from multiple clients only with an API.
Or What is the best practice in the same situation.
Any help?

Comment: Why would you need to call the API three times?

Comment: @dreamcrash, Thanks for your reply. 
First for the custom-defined client (named `ABC`).

Second for `realm-management` client roles,(without having this client we can't query users)

And Third for `realm` roles. (roles belongs to the realm, not the clients)

Comment: @dreamcrash, Question edited for better untrestanding

Comment: AFIAK, if you are using the Keycloak Rest Admin API you will have to make the three calls. I don't remember by heart but if you know the name of the roles of the client ID you can try to directly call an endpoint to assign those roles to the user

Comment: @dreamcrash, thank you for your valuable suggestion, but at the first step we should show the role list to the admin user in the front-end, and after that, we can call the related API for assigning